# Getting started with malware research

Tags: career-advice

I followed some reverse engineering tutorials and they got me really interested.
And I heard that you could make a career out of it, mostly from malware research.

So... how can I learn about malware research and get a job doing it?

P.S. What are other fields of professional reverse engineering (which aren't malicious) are there?

Answer (score 2):

As for getting experience analyzing malware, see the following two posts:

- [How can I analyze a potentially harmful binary safely?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-analyze-a-potentially-harmful-binary-safely)
- [Where can I, as an individual, get malware samples to analyze?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206/where-can-i-as-an-individual-get-malware-samples-to-analyze)

[The Art of Computer Virus Research and Defense](http://amzn.com/0321304543) is a bit outdated, but at the very least it will give you some history on malware research.

As for other professional reverse engineering jobs:

- Vulnerability research and exploit development (consulting, independent research, etc.)
- Designing and developing anti-reversing technologies (commercial packers, DRM, etc.)
- Education industry (academia, conference training)
- Government work

Also see [How do I move from RCE being a hobby to RCE being a profession?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/how-do-i-move-from-rce-being-a-hobby-to-rce-being-a-profession)