# Where can I get Linux malware samples?

Tags: malware, linux, elf

There have been numerous sites stated in this wonderful [post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206/where-can-i-as-an-individual-get-malware-samples-to-analyze) that one could retrieve malware samples. However, I am having a difficult time (sorry D:) locating Linux-specific malware from those sites as mostly are samples for Windows (I think). Where can I find and download these Linux samples that I seek?

BTW, this is for learning to create ClamAV and YARA signatures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to pay for [VirusTotal's Private API](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/private-api/), you can search for and download Linux malware from there.

A sample search for Linux ELF files with 5 or more AV detections would be [`magic:elf positives:5+`](https://www.virustotal.com/intelligence/search/?query=magic%3Aelf%20positives%3A5%2B) (file hashes blurred in the screenshot below) -

[image: VirusTotal]

Answer (score 5):

You can also sign up for [VirusShare](http://virusshare.com/) and download the following archive which has 2778 ELF samples :
VirusShare_ELF_20140617.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain files from https://www.virussamples.com and download many ELF and PE files among others.  There are daily batches available.