# where i can get android malware samples to analyze?

Tags: malware

Is there any sites to get new android malware files(.apk files) for analysing purpose?
and also suggest me some blogs/sites for android malware analysis?
Please reply me ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/9282/1562 in particular (replace "Linux" with "Android"), and http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206/where-can-i-as-an-individual-get-malware-samples-to-analyze in general.

Answer (score 0):

VirusShare has a really nice collection of Android malware:
[VirusShare](https://virusshare.com)

[image: example]

Comment: If you have virustotal account you can get a lot of hash from https://www.apk-analyzer.net and http://sanddroid.xjtu.edu.cn/#overview