# Where can I, as an individual, find clean programs to analyze?

Tags: windows, malware

[This question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/206/17483) includes a good list of sources where an individual might collect malware samples for analysis.

I'd like to get a large number of public, non-malicious programs for the purpose of comparing various attributes to malware samples.

I have explored the following options:

- **Scraping executables from arbitrary websites with a bot.** Such a bot would be rather difficult to write, not to mention being unethical, and requiring strategies to deal with anti-bot measures such as CloudFlare.
- **Using C:\Windows as a source.** I spent some time looking at some Windows files. They were abundant, but all seem to perform extremely specialized functions and I have doubts about how well they would represent legitimate programs in the real world
- **Finding and downloading programs manually.** This would be extremely slow and tedious, and also ineffective to get large numbers of such programs.

I suppose what would be ideal for my situation is a sort of program dump, but I'm not aware of any that exist.

As someone unaffiliated with any organisation, is there an effective way of getting a large number of public normal programs for the purpose of comparing their features to a set of malicious programs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find benign samples with a high potential to false positive?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13428/where-can-i-find-benign-samples-with-a-high-potential-to-false-positive)

Comment: If you are not limited by using Windows as a base OS, you have a lot of pre-compiled programs in Ubuntu and other Linux related repositories, for example here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12261/benign-portable-executables

Comment: @Nordwald it's also a duplicate of a question that wasn't closed as off-topic, with more helpful answers. see my comment.

Comment: @Nirlzr Regardless, the closed topic may be more strongly related. The reasoning behind this decision may apply here as well.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, I would suggest shareware aggregators, for example

- http://download.cnet.com/windows/
- http://www.tucows.com/windows
- http://padsites.org/

and/or archive sites:

- http://cd.textfiles.com/
- http://www.oldversion.com/