# Anti-VM and anti-sandbox malware samples

Tags: malware, virtual-machines, sandbox

I'm learning malware analysis.
I'm looking for malware samples that terminate themselves when recognize working on a VM or sandbox.

Thanks.

Comment: This relates to http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206/where-can-i-as-an-individual-get-malware-samples-to-analyze

Comment: I propose having a look at early cerber samples (9e82344a0a854411fd095f070b0782e8), they feature a debug mode, few obfuscation tricks and the whole range of basic anti-vm-techniques (have a look at 0x401307)

Comment: @Nordwald Do you know where I can download these samples of cerber? (I have tried searching with the given hash but cannot found any)

Comment: @TaThanhDinh This is only the hash of a sample I analyzed personally, but any of the early-samples should suffice as an example. Sadly, apart from commercial solutions like VirusTotal, malware repositories are awfully bad maintained. You may try malpedia or openMalware for example

Answer (score 6):

For learning purposes, I would recommend you the following Github projects to start with:

**Paranoid Fish by a0rtega**

https://github.com/a0rtega/pafish

**Al-Khaser v0.60 by Noteworthy**

https://github.com/LordNoteworthy/al-khaser

or

**Colection by AlicanAkyol**

https://github.com/AlicanAkyol/sems

Grab one you like, compile and analyze.

In case you look for in the wild samples, you should look at Andromeda\Gamarue bot. It have a plenty of anti tricks, including anti-VM, anti-Sandbox, anti-research etc.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/a0rtega/pafish is old but it is good tool.
https://github.com/AlicanAkyol/sems is current. You can use it.

Comment: Answers that are merely links are not encouraged, may I interest you writing at least a couple of sentences about the tools?

Comment: I used the tools for malware analysis. And these tools have given successful result. But I like sems more than pafish.