# Finding a specific malware sample

Tags: malware

I am trying to find for analysis the `scuinst.exe` binary (R2D2 aka Bundestrojaner), but I can not find it.

Where can I find this binary?

Comment: The best is probably to find out the relevant SHA1 (or other hash) and then have a look [at this topic](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/206/245) to find a place where - by looking up the hash - you can download a sample. The reason all the answers in that other topic are community wikis is because this is actually off-topic here. So this question will eventually be closed.

Answer (score 3):

A simple search revealed that it can be found on VirusTotal by searching for md5sum `309ede406988486bf81e603c514b4b82`:

https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/021da2f5e892265cafd1642a44fe258ee56cf6e1393f6e0dc79add99fed1f15f/detection

For more information refer to the following articles:

- https://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00002250.html
- https://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00002249.html
- https://www.evild3ad.com/1136/volatility-memory-forensics-federal-trojan-aka-r2d2/